# asp.net core mvc razor page css not loading on specific route

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

I have setup a new/basic Asp.Net Core MVC project. All the CSS and JS are working fine when I am on homepage:

[image]

But when I go to some specific route like "/Role/Create", CSS and JS files are not loading correctly:

[image]

The error basically originates from jquery.min.js and I am not sure why its prepending /Role before /assets in the url. I might be missing a very small thing.

Here is the complete code:
https://github.com/alishahzadone/WebApplicationMvc

Comment: use `~/jquery.min.js`

Comment: add a `~/` before your assets links

Comment: @NimaTalebi its already there, please check GitHub repo: https://github.com/alishahzadone/WebApplicationMvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because the css files path is relative to your page route not to the base path
you can fix it by adding

`<base href="~/">`

in your layout page `_layout.cshtml` before the `<head>` tag